# \longtable column is too wide. Why?

Tags: longtable

why is the second column too wide (cmidrule?)?
What can I do about it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=1.3cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{numprint}

\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\makecell{Diameter\\base}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\makecell{Door\\position}}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\makecell{Diameter\\base}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\makecell{Door\\position}}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Continued on next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
175.0 & 4.00\\
210.0 & 5.00\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to add an image of the output. It seems that even if it is not being used the `Continued on next page` elemement is taken into account.

Comment: If this is just an intermediate stage and you are expecting the table to get wider anyway, don't worry, it will go away. If this is the final width (just two number columns), then think about abbreviating `Continued on next page` to `Continued` or `Cont.~next p.`. Or pack the text into an `\rlap` command (`\rlap{Continued ....}`), then the footer with have zero width and will extend beyond the table border.

Comment: Note that in this case `\multicolumn{1}{l}` does nothing useful.  It doesn't change the column format and doesn't add or remove vertical liens.

Comment: John Kormylo: The Tex source is generated by (my) C# code

Comment: daleif & gernot: indeed works. thnx